# Open Meta Data not able to create ingestion JSON files on Airflow Folder -dag_generated_configs

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, metadata, kubernetes-helm, aws-glue

[image]I am working on setting up **bare metal deployment** for OMD (Open Meta Data), luckily able to set up all the components, but facing some issues with the Airflow Ingestion Service. It seems like the OMD-created JSON Files are not getting stored in the Airflow Path (**dag_generated_configs**/ folder).
Attached is a screenshot of the error.
Please let me know how I can resolve this ingestion issue.

In the Kubernetes deployment method, I can see the below config option
`    config:

```
AIRFLOW__OPENMETADATA_AIRFLOW_APIS__DAG_GENERATED_CONFIGS: 
"/airflow-dags/dags"`
```

but in bare metal deployment documentation, I can't see this option available. Is this issue to that?

**FYI My Setup - **

1. OMD Version 0,13.0
2. I am using  AWS RDS as a meta DB ,
3. AWS Open Search
4. OMD backend Application and airflow standalone on the same EC2 server for now

**FYI my Airflow configurations in OMD YAML File**

`
airflowConfiguration:

```
   apiEndpoint: http://<server i.p>:8080
   hostIp: ${AIRFLOW_HOST_IP:-""}
   username: user
   password: pass
   metadataApiEndpoint: ${SERVER_HOST_API_URL:- 
   http://localhost:8585/api}
   authProvider: ${AIRFLOW_AUTH_PROVIDER:-"no-auth"} # 
   Possible values are "no-auth",     "azure", "google", 
   "okta", "auth0", "custom-oidc", "openmetadata"
   authConfig:
     azure:
       clientSecret: ${OM_AUTH_AIRFLOW_AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET:-""}
       authority: ${OM_AUTH_AIRFLOW_AZURE_AUTHORITY_URL:-""}
       scopes: ${OM_AUTH_AIRFLOW_AZURE_SCOPES:-[]}
       clientId: ${OM_AUTH_AIRFLOW_AZURE_CLIENT_ID:-""}`
```

Tried things -
I Tried Creating the Folder - **dag_generated_configs** into the Airflow home path & then ran the ingestion, but still faced the same.
To make sure that there is no connectivity issue between OMD & Airflow I hosted them on the same Ec2 Server

Expectations -

1. I want to know why the JSON files are not being created on airflow.
2. How can provide airflow home path in bare metal deployment, which config to change

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new directory 'home/ec2-user/airflow/dag_generated_configs' and open the airflow configuration file.
By default, the dags_folder is set to /path/to/airflow/dags, but you can change it to your desired location. Here's how to mention the DAGs folder path in the airflow.cfg file:

Search for dags_folder: Look for the dags_folder option in the airflow.cfg file. It should look like this:

dags_folder = /home/ec2-user/airflow/dag_generated_configs

Save the changes: After updating the dags_folder, save the changes to the airflow.cfg file.Restart the Airflow services: After making changes to the airflow.cfg file, you need to restart the Airflow services (scheduler, webserver, workers, etc.) for the changes to take effect.

Now you need to create a new connection and run the ingestion pipeline and it works fine.
Enjoy.